# How to see Dart code stack trace instead of Java code stack trace in Crashlytics/Flutter (Android)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, crashlytics

We are using the `firebase_crashlytics` plugin for Flutter to get error reports in Crashlytics. Unfortunately for Android, only the **non-fatal** issues show a proper Dart code stack trace. The **fatal** issues only show Java code stack trace which makes them very hard to debug.

Is there any way to get proper Dart code stack traces for fatal issues as well?

Comment: Have you found any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I added this lines to my `main.dart` to get the Dart StackTrace:

```
FlutterError.onError = (error) => flutterErrorHandler(error);

runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(
    () async => runApp(
      YourAppWidget(),
    ),
    (error, strack) async {
      debugPrint(error.toString());
      // Whenever an error occurs, call the `reportCrash`
      // to send Dart errors to Crashlytics
      Crashlytics.instance.recordError(error, strack);
    },
  );
```

```
void flutterErrorHandler(FlutterErrorDetails details) {
  FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);

  // Report to the application zone to report to Crashlytics.
  Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(details.exception, details.stack);
}
```

For more details see: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out.

Comment: Is the suggested answer working? if not what are the other options i can go with?